# How can I float the login to the right?

Tags: html, css

Basically what I am trying to do is to shift the Login menu all the way to the right. Just as you see all the menu is left aligned, I need to right align the Login menu. The issue is that I do not know where to start.

Here is where the navigation menu is generated from the array list in nav.php :

```
<ul>
 <?php 
      foreach ($navItems as $item) { 
          echo "<li><a href=\"$item[slug]\"><h2>$item[title]</h2></a></li>";                         
      }
 ?>

</ul>
```

And here is the array list where it is coming from in array.php :-

```
<?php
//Navigation Menu Items

 $navItems =array( 
        array(
            'slug' => "index.php",
            'title' => "Home"
            ),
        array(
            'slug' => "about.php",
            'title' => "About Us"
            ),
        array(
            'slug' => "why.php",
            'title' => "Why Us"
            ),
        array(
            'slug' => "what.php",
            'title' => "What's Included"
            ),
        array(
            'slug' => "faq.php",
            'title' => "FAQs"
            ),
        array(
            'slug' => "contact.php",
            'title' => "Contact Us"
            ),
        array(
            'slug' => "login.php",
            'title' => "Login"
            ),
  );

?>
```

And yet in another file called spacer.php they are included:

```
   <nav>
        <h2 class="hidden">Our navigation</h2>
          <?php include 'includes/nav.php'; ?>

   </nav>
```

And here is the css for it :-

```
nav{   
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index: 300;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-shadow:0px 1px #D6D0C1 ;
}

nav ul
{
    list-style:none;
}

nav ul li
{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:25px 25px;
}

nav ul li a
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}

nav ul li a:hover
{
    color:#A0522D;
}
```

You can view a live example here http://cleanereview.ca

Comment: Your link isn't showing a login menu at all

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant to your question. Please remove the tag and post the rendered HTML in your question. Also a stack snippet or jsFiddle showing the issue would be helpful.

Comment: please dont advertise website here...

Comment: @Andrew I am not advertising

Comment: @j08691
Suggestions to resolve the issue will be more helpful !

Comment: @Lee
Scroll down a little bit on the website

Comment: @Andrew
Its a client website I do not get a penny for putting it up here

Comment: I can't make suggestions until you post the proper code, but thanks for schooling me on how to use this site.

Comment: @UmarAftab an example on JSFiddle is best, the main reason for this isn't advertising, it because once you've fixed the problem on the client site the example, and the question, have no meaning or much use for future users

Comment: @ToniLeigh
Ok thanks for the heads up and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it float to the right...

```
nav ul li:last-child
{
    float:right;
}
```

Or put class or id on it and make the selector simpler.

AS PER FURTHER REQUIREMENT:

```
<li>
    <a href="login.php">
        <h2><img style="width: 16px;" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/bitsies/128/Enter-128.png"> <span>Login</span>
        </h2>
    </a>
</li>
```

This is one of a thousand possibilities (as putting the image on the background, positioning it in an absolute position or relative to something else, etc.)

I think you should study some html and css before starting the adventure of creating a web site... There're plenty of good resources on internet for that, just google for it.

Comment: And how do I add an image alongside it if I want to add any ?

Comment: This would be another question... But where do you want the image to be placed?

Comment: Right next to the li item. Only the login item ?

Comment: I marked this as an answer but I do not have privileges for an up vote.

Comment: put a class on it *not* an ID

Comment: @Vi100
Thanks for your answer ! I was not asking about displaying an image in html/css because that is simple. I am generating the menu from the array in the question. But let me try to add it to the last-child, I just completely forgot about it.